# with jQuery doesn't work(function is not being executed)

Tags: jquery, reference

```
<ul class="mobile-menu">
<li class="m-con" id="toggle_side-bar_menu" onclick="menu();"><a href="javascript://" onclick="menu();" class="menu_toggle"><span class="ico-menu_tgl"><span class="ico_sprite-line"></div></span></a></li>
<li class="search-toggle" onclick="search();">
<a href="#" onclick="search(); return false;" class="search-close"></a>
<form method="get" action="/search">
<input class="execute" type="submit" name="s" value="" />
<input class="search hidden" type="text" />
</form>
</li>
```

```
opensea = false;
function search() {
    var element = $(".search-toggle");
    if(!opensea) {
        menu_close();
        $(".search-toggle").addClass("active");
        $(".search-toggle .search").removeClass("hidden").addClass("expanded");
        opensea = true;
    } else {
        search_close();
    };
}
function search_close() {
    $(".search-toggle .search").removeClass("expanded").addClass("hidden");
    $(".search-toggle").removeClass("active");
    opensea = false;
}
```

I can not get this code to work it only works on the element ".search-toggle",I have tried to create a new element `<a href="" onclick="search();"></a>`, but to my avail it does not work. Also your browser has to be mobile size;resize your window or ctrl+shift+m.
website: http://test.days4god.com

Same issue is present here. Am I not coding not along the lines of compatibility  with the jQuery framework I have?
Sorry for stating jQuery doesn't work, it works but the function is not being executed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu li a").click(function(e) {
        var submenucheck = $(this).parent();
        if(submenucheck.has(".submenu").length > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var element = $(this).parent().find(".submenu");
            var sub = $(this).parent().find(".submenu");
            if (element.hasClass("toggle")) {
                sub.css("display","none").removeClass("toggle");
            } else {
                sub.css("display","block").addClass("toggle");
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

For this piece of code(above) I get this error: "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.".
Back to the first question: Inside my console I get this error, "ReferenceError: opensea is not defined". Hopefully this will clear things up, alongside the new title.

Comment: You're going to have to take some time to explain what you expect this code segment to do and what it's doing different from those expectations.  Your current explanation is unclear.

Comment: Well what I want to is create an element with .search-toggle, "<a href="#" onclick="search(); return false;"></a>", it will be style with css, but basically a button, in which will trigger the following function, "search();". But the problem is it does not work. Maybe you want me to demonstrate a part of it in HTML?

Comment: Still not enough information;you seem to just be reiterating what you wrote earlier.  You should edit your question and include all of the relevant code.  Also, how does the "days4god" link relate to your question?  You should be able to use https://jsfiddle.net/ for working code segments to illustration your problem in a more focused manner.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNPWcdoYSBA&feature=youtu.be

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/taqde5zy/

Comment: Hopefully the video helps

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v3Ljssbo/
why does it not work?

Comment: In order for something to be considered "working" there need to be an objective description of the expected behavior.  In software engineering this description is known as technical requirements.  I've watched the video and I've gone to both of the jsfiddle projects, but nowhere have you clearly stated your expectations of the code's behavior and how it fails to meet those expectations.  Please edit your question to clearly and concisely do so.  Until you do so, you're unlikely to get much help in this forum.

Comment: Here is the error I get: ReferenceError: menu is not defined. I want to create a separate element apart from using that li....search-toggle, "<a href="#" onclick="search(); return false;"></a>",  once you click on I use variables defined in the function if statements...var = true or false to define whether the menu is opened or not. 

Apart from this,I believe I am not properly defining var.

Comment: I know I can use the toggle function which is basic, but I don't want to use basics, I want to move, as I comfortable handling loads of adv jquery.

Comment: By working I mean functioning properly.

Comment: I believe the best thing I could do is review as my language may be way to complicated for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by defining a variable not properly, the issue was fixed by putting var right before "opensea = false;".
- Thank you! for your help, I have been having doubts on how I used my var.

```
var opensea = false;
function search() {
    var element = $(".search-toggle");
    if(!opensea) {
        menu_close();
        element.addClass("active");
        element.removeClass("hidden").addClass("expanded");
        opensea = true;
    } else {
        search_close();
    };
}
function search_close() {
    $(".search-toggle .search").removeClass("expanded").addClass("hidden");
    $(".search-toggle").removeClass("active");
    opensea = false;
}
```